# Getting the dates of a week

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I need to get all the dates of a week for the current month only when I pressed a specific date. For example, if I pressed Sept 28, the result will be Sept 23-28 dates but if I pressed Sept 30, the result will be Sept 30 ONLY because the dates after that are for October.

This is my code to get the dates of a week:

```
extension Date {
    var startOfWeek: Date? {
        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        guard let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self)) else { return nil }
        return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 0, to: sunday)
    }

    var endOfWeek: Date? {
        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        guard let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self)) else { return nil }
        return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 6, to: sunday)
    }
}
```

But for this code the result is Sept 30 - Oct 6 which is not what I want. Pls help

Comment: Keep in mind that your logic also needs to deal with different starting days of the week in different locales. For locales that start the week on a Monday, the dates you want for September 30, 2018 would be Sept 24-30.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder but this will have a fixed locale.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the last day of the month, and then `endOfWeek` would be the minimum between what you already have and the end of the month.

```
var endOfWeek: Date? {
    let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    guard let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self)) else { return nil }
    let endOfWeek = gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 6, to: sunday)
    let firstOfNextMonth = gregorian.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: sunday)
    let lastOfThisMonth = gregorian.date(byAdding: .day: value: -1, to: firstOfNextMonth)

    return min(endOfWeek, lastOfThisMonth)
}
```

I can't guarantee that that code will compile but it should give you an idea of how to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend [SwiftMoment](https://github.com/akosma/SwiftMoment) as it's a Swift port of [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Moment.js is a rich library that has great documentation and super useful functions for this purpose.

Given a `date`, you can get the `start of week Date`, and `end of week Date`.

Then from there, you can enumerate the dates in between.

I'm currently using Moment.js in my web app project with this function to get the week dates given a date:

```
getWeekDates (dateReference, format) {
    const startOfWeek = moment(dateReference).startOf('isoWeek');
    const endOfWeek = moment(dateReference).endOf('isoWeek');

    var days = [];
    var day = startOfWeek;

    while (day <= endOfWeek) {
        if (format !== undefined) {
          days.push(day.format(format));
        } else {
          days.push(day);
        }
        day = day.clone().add(1, 'd');
    }

    return days;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could intersect the intervals for the week and month containing the date.

Here's a quick test:

```
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let date = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: 2018, month: 9, day: 30).date!

let weekComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: date)
let startOfWeek = calendar.date(from: weekComponents)!
let endOfWeek = calendar.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: 1, to: startOfWeek)!
let weekInterval = DateInterval(start: startOfWeek, end: endOfWeek)

let monthComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: date)
let startOfMonth = calendar.date(from: monthComponents)!
let endOfMonth = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: startOfMonth)!
let monthInterval = DateInterval(start: startOfMonth, end: endOfMonth)

let targetRange = monthInterval.intersection(with: weekInterval)!
let firstDay = targetRange.start
let lastDay = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: targetRange.end)
```

You'll want to refactor to avoid force unwrapping all the dates.